# How to add navigation controller in View Based Application in iPhone?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

My application is view based appln. So how can i implement navigation controller in my apps.

If i have used this code, my controller works fine.

```
   FirstClass *first = [[FirstClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstClass" bundle:nil];

   [self presentModalViewController:first animated:NO];
```

But using navigation controller in my apps, the navigation controller doesn't work.

```
    FirstClass *first = [[FirstClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstClass" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigNews = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first] autorelease(or retain)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigNews animated:YES];
```

So how can i add the navigation controller in my application. If i have added the navigation controller in my root view, i have faced some problem. so how can i add the navigation controller in the particular view.

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

[self.view addSubview:navigNews.view];